# Response.write doesn't display image

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to display a generated image like so:

```
Response.Write("<img src='" & filepather & "'/>")
```

Where filepather is defined as the string to the image. It is the correct filepath, and I'm not getting the "broken image link" icon. This code is located in a vb script inside an aspx page.

Have I forgotten something here? If I do

```
response.write("hello"),
```

it works fine.

Comment: can you post the link or a jsFiddle?

Comment: What kind of image is it? Can you open the source of the output, copy the image link and open in a new browser?

Comment: What is the generated html output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure `filepather` string contains the virtual address of the image not the physical address.

Like I have tested this and works fine.

```
Dim filePath As String = "http://localhost:2025/Styles/Images/logo.png"
Response.Write("<img src='" & filePath & "'/>")
```

Comment: Thanks! Thats the problem.